# Need Eclipse like maven goals life cycle with Intelli Idea

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

The actual question is asked here: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5458663#5458663

Could any body answer how to get the maven life cycle goals when right click project in Idea ?

Thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ has a view called "Maven Projects". Open it and you will see (and can execute) the standard lifecycle phases (clean, compile, package etc.). Through right-click on a phase you can create a Launch Configuration using the "Create..." menu entry.

In the view's preferences menu, you can uncheck "Show Basic Phases Only" to get access to more exotic phases like "pre-integration-test"